# How to update UI before nsoperation will start and or end

Tags: nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

2 part question but related so will keep in the same thread:

I'm adding `NSOperations` to a `NSOperationQueue`. I need to know when the operation will start and when it ends in order to update the UI.

I thought about adding a "start handler" block to run in the nsoperation as well as a "completion handler" in the NSOperation

Something like

```
-(id)initOperationWithStartBlock:(StartBlock)startblock completionBlock:(CompletionBlock)completionBlock
```

but believe that there is a better way to get this from the queue itself.

How can this be done?

I would also like to know the index of the job sent by the NSOperationQueue.

I've tried doing

```
[[self.myQueue operations] indexForObject:operation]
```

but the index is always the zeroth index - because the completed jobs were removed from the nsoperationqueue array before I could check the jobs index.

Any way to preserve them?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Key-Value-Observing pattern in IOS. So for this you need to setup observers in your controller to look for changes to isFinished and isExecuting to catch start and finish hooks.

Comment: will that block the queue from sending the next job?

Comment: Nopes. The KVO is managed by central dispatch and wont block your operation.

Answer (score -2):

It depends if you want to perform something from within your object upon starting or elsewhere in your code. From what you are saying (you want to update the UI), this sounds like you want to act outside of your object, but I don't know your program. You have two options:

1) If you want to act in your object upon starting the operation from within the same object, use key-value observation and observe isExecuting with self as the observer and the observed.  Don't forget that you will get called whether it goes from NO to YES (starting) or YES to NO (done).

2) If you want to perform an action outside of the object, I would rather recommend to use the very general NSNotification with NSNotificationCenter and within your main, post a notification such as @"willStart" and @"didComplete". In any other object, register as an observer for your notifications.

Either way, don't forget that notifications are sent in the current threads but the UI must be updated on the main thread. You don't know on what thread observe:keyPath: is called.  You may need to call performSelectorOnMainThread to update the UI or you can even use the convenient and useful nsoperationqueue mainqueue with a addOperationWithBlock with your UI code. If you use the NotificationCenter, then you can simply yourself post on the main thread with nsobject performSelectorOnMainThread